# Modify string to seo url but keep Scandinavian letters

Tags: php, url, seo, preg-replace

I am having trouble with understanding how to keep the norwegian letters
"æ ø å" in this preg_replace function i got for modifying forum titles into SEO URLs.
My website is rendered in "iso-8859-1".

**How i want it:** someurl.com/read=kjøp_og_salg

**Currently looks like this:** someurl.com/read=kj_p_og_salg

```
//----- The seo url function ------//
    public function make_seo_name($title){
    $title = preg_replace('/[\'"]/', '', $title);
    $title = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/', '_', $title);
    $title = strtolower(trim($title, '_'));
    return $title;
}
```

I tried to `utf8_encode/decode` the `$title` before and after the `preg_replace` was done, but didn't work.

Thank you for your time!

**EDIT:**

Solved, i fixed it with some help from "One Trick Pony". I ended up with this function.

```
public function make_seo_name($title){
  $title = utf8_encode($title);
  $title = preg_replace('/[\'"]/', '', $title);
  $title = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\Ã¸\Ã¥\Ã¦]+/', '_', $title);
  $title = strtolower(trim($title, '_'));
return $title;
}
```

*Note:* i did NOT need to change my  header from "iso-8859-1" to "UTF-8"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `'/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/'` bit is a [regular expression](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596528124) that says to match only characters that are *not* the characters `a` through `z`, `A` through `Z`, or `0` through `9`. The basic syntax is [on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions).

`preg_replace` then replaces such characters with underscores.

You can add the extra characters you want to allow to this list:

```
$title = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9æøå]+/', '_', $title);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the document encoding to utf-8 or iso-8859-1 and add the characters to the list like:

```
<head><meta charset="utf-8" /></head>
```

and

```
$title = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9æøå]+/', '_', $title);
```